# How can I open app using c# winform and close the winform without closing the opened app?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm using this code to open ms access database :

```
  public partial class Start_Baseet : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        string MyFile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Baseet.accde";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application AccApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();

        public Start_Baseet()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void OpenDb()
        {
            AccApp.Visible = true;
            AccApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(MyFile, false, "017014a");
            AccApp.RunCommand(AcCommand.acCmdAppMaximize);

        }
        private void Start_Basset_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OpenDb();
            }
            catch
            {
                AccApp.Quit();
                MessageBox.Show("Missing Files", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

It's working but when the `Finally` part executed `This.Close` the opened access database closes , How can I use this code and close the form without closing the opened access database ?
Thanks

Edit#1 : I used this but still having the problem

```
static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            //Application.Run(new Start_Baseet());
            Start_Baseet frm = new Start_Baseet();
            frm.Show();
        }
```

Edit#2 I discovered another problem , I have two PC's the first running office 2016 32-bit and the other 2016 64-bit. The first one where I developed this app when I debug or release the ms access application opens but the database `Baseet.accde` don't open .
The second PC when I try to run the released app it works fine ! why is this ??!!

Comment: If you close your main form, the application ends. You can change the main form in Program.cs to other Form (not visible) that in the Load show you current main form. In this way, closing your form don't close the App, but you must manage this situation: how interact now the user with the non-visible application? What must do the application after close your form?

Comment: **Edit #1**: is missing `Application.Run();` after `frm.Show();`. **Edit #2**: set the Platform target from `AnyCPU` to `x86` in the project Properties / Build / General, so that the app always runs in 32-bit mode. This is necessary as your MS Access is 32-bit.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thanks for your reply , The first point is done thanks , About the Edit#2 I changed the target platform to x86 but this time neither of the 2 PC's ran the app correctly it stuck with the main access window and didn't open the target db , Thanks for your patience

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes My bad I mixed the files between the two PC's and they are accde so it can't be run on different architecture , Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Form from `Application.Run();` and open the form explicitly with `frm.Show();`

Instead of

```cs
Application.Run(new Start_Baseet());
```

Use

```cs
var frm = new Start_Baseet();
frm.Show();
Application.Run();
```

Now you must leave the application with `Application.Exit();`. Closing the form will not terminate the application any more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , Please have alook on Edit#1 in my post , Still have the problem.

Comment: And discovered another problem please have a look  on Edit#2